# Where can I find alchemy recipes?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the new Mists of Pandaria expansion, the profession level caps have been increased from 525 to 600. I have gone to my alchemy trainer to learn the next level of alchemy (Zen Grandmaster Alchemy) but there only appears to be a couple of new alchemy recipes to learn and nothing else.

The recipes I learned were:

- [Alchemist's Rejuvenation](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=114751/alchemists-rejuvenation)
- [Alchemist's Flask](http://www.wowhead.com/spell=114786) which looks like a replacement for an old recipe with updated effects

Furthermore, looking on WoWhead, [there does appear to be any alchemist recipes above 525](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=65186#teaches-recipe:0-16+1+3).

Where can I find alchemy recipes?

but there doesn't appear to be any other alchemy recipes I can learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to all recipes, however most of them cannot be trained but must be discovered by making the two you mention

From the [official site](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/7305441/Mists_of_Pandaria_Professions_The_Art_of_Discovery-9_18_2012):

> In Mists of Pandaria, the method in which one learns the ways of the
>   alchemist has changed fundamentally. When first learning this
>   profession, players will find only two recipes available from the
>   trainer. From then on, the path to mastery is paved with the joy of
>   discovery. As you level your Alchemy skills, you’ll be able to learn
>   more recipes as you go. Skill and discovery go hand in hand and you
>   won’t be able to discover some recipes until you reach the appropriate
>   skill level.

Comment: Additionally, you can see the MoP recipes here by reversing the list: http://www.wowhead.com/skill=171#recipes:0+16+1

Answer (score 1):

According to [WoWHead's guide for MoP](http://www.wowhead.com/news=203845/mists-of-pandaria-alchemy-preview):

> Learning recipes is very different in Mists of Pandaria. When first
>   learning the profession, players will only get two recipes from the
>   trainer and learn more recipes from creating consumables. Discovered
>   recipes can also reveal additional recipes when created.